# RXJava2 "neverending" Observable

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm new to RX and got stuck with the next:

I'm using SQLBrite and when query method is called it gives me back a "neverending" Observable which listens to the db changes. When some items are emitted - I need to make some async calls in a loop and give back that items which I received. The sample code:

```
public Observable<List<Entity>> execute() {
   return someManager.getAccount()
            .take(1)  // I do not need RX to trigger updates when account changed, so use take(1)
            .flatMap(accountOptional -> {
                if (accountOptional.isPresent()) {
                    SomeAccount account = accountOptional.get();
                    return someManager.getEntityDataSource()
                            .query(new EntitySpecification(account.getId()));
                }
                return Observable.just(new ArrayList<Entity>()); // No account - no entities
            })
            .flatMapIterable(entities -> entities)  // Here I have a list of entities i I need to make async calls to fill entities with some iiner data (some other entities)
            .flatMap(this::loadInnerData)
            .toList()  
            .toObservable();
}


private Observable<Entity> loadInnerData(Entity entity) {
    return do some work with entity;
   }
```

The trouble comes when I use toList() - it waits till Observable ends it's job - but it will not be done, as this observable is listening to the db. How can I achieve ability to listen to not stop listening to the "neverending" Observable and loop async calls with RX (as it is done with loadInnerData())?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with

```
    return Observable.create(new Action1<Emitter<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Emitter<String> stringEmitter) {
          // here u can use onNext / onError
                            stringEmitter.onNext(s);

                            stringEmitter.onError(e);
                        }
                    });

            stringEmitter.setCancellation(new Cancellable() {
                @Override
                public void cancel() throws Exception {
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                }
            });
        }
    }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
```